# How to use this operator of "?i"

Tags: java, syntax, case-insensitive

I have learned Java for about 3 weeks. I saw statements like below

```
String str="I am a Member of MU";

str=str.replaceFirst("(?i)m", "");
```

Basically, the function of the above statements is to replace(delete) the first "m" ignoring case. It seems to me that "?i" is some kind of operator to ignore case of a character. Can anybody please explain to me how to use this "?i"? I can't find anywhere the detailed syntax of "?i". Thanks

Comment: You are looking for *regular expressions*. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: As the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst) indicates the first parameter is a [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). You can see that `?i` actually turns the `i` flags on in your case the case insensitive.

Comment: See this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).  What you're looking at is a regular expression (regex), which is not part of the Java language but rather defined by the libraries.  Regexes are also used by library routines in other languages and are built-in to some languages.  The syntax is pretty much the same but there are variations.

Answer (score 0):

It is a "Special constructs" per [lngo's link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special)

> `(?idmsuxU-idmsuxU) - Nothing, but turns match flags i d m s u x U on - off`

Which means in your case

> `(?i) matches nothing, but turns on flag i (case insensitive).`

Matching nothing is important so that you don't replace more than just an `m`.

Comment: For example, if Yoda is a member of MU, the result of `"Member of MU I am"` will be `"ember of MU I am"`. It just means "match 'm' ignoring case".